# Translating C pointer code example to Delphi pointer syntax

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, translate

I am working with a binary file structure. The code example for reading the data is in C, and I need to read it in Delphi. I hasten to add I have no C programming experience.

Given the following

```
typedef struct {
uchar ID, DataSource;
ushort ChecksumOffset;
uchar Spare, NDataTypes;
ushort Offset [256];
} HeaderType; 

...

typedef struct {
ushort ID;
...
ushort DistanceToBin1Middle,TransmitLength;
} FixLeaderType;

...

HeaderType *HdrPtr;
FixLeaderType *FLdrPtr;

unsigned char RcvBuff[8192];
void DecodeBBensemble( void )
{
unsigned short i, *IDptr, ID;
FLdrPtr = (FixLeaderType *)&RcvBuff [ HdrPtr->Offset[0] ];
if (FLdrPtr->NBins > 128)
FLdrPtr->NBins = 32;

...
```

The bit I am having difficulty following is this:

```
FLdrPtr = (FixLeaderType *)&RcvBuff [ HdrPtr->Offset[0] ];
```

From the little I understand, `[ HdrPtr->Offset[0] ];`  would be returning the value of the first Offset array item from the HeaderType struct pointed to by HdrPtr? So equivalent to `HdrPtr^.Offset[0]` ?

Then `&RcvBuff [ HdrPtr->Offset[0] ];` should be returning the memory address containing the value of the RcvBuff array item indexed, so equivalent to `@RecBuff[HdrPtr^.Offset[0]]` ?

Then I get lost with `(FixLeaderType *)..` . Could someone please help  explain exactly what is being referenced by FldrPtr ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bits of code that are relevant are

```
FixLeaderType *FLdrPtr; 
unsigned char RcvBuff[8192]; 

FLdrPtr = (FixLeaderType *)&RcvBuff [ HdrPtr->Offset[0] ];
```

1. `FldPtr` is of type `FixLeaderType *`, or pointer to `FixLeaderType`.
2. `RcvBuff` is an array of `char`.
3. `HdrPtr->Offset[0]` resolves to an ushort value, so `RcvBuff [ HdrPtr->Offset[0] ]` yields a `char` value.
4. The `&` means that instead of getting the value of the `char` the address of the value is returned. Note that this means that it is of type `char *`.
5. The `char *` type is the wrong type to assign to `FldPtr`. The `(FixLeaderType *)` converts the type so that it is valid. This is called a cast operation.

Comment: Thank you! The typecast operation was the bit I was missing. That clears things up enough for me to continue. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

i think you should read those like:

```
* = pointer to

& = address of
```

that makes things a lot easier